# Why can't borrow-checker drop reference in Arc::get_mut None case

Tags: rust, automatic-ref-counting, lifetime, borrow-checker

Trying to do something like

```
use std::sync::Arc;

struct Foo(Arc<Bar>);

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Bar;

impl Foo {
    fn bar_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Bar {
        match Arc::get_mut(&mut self.0) {
            Some(bar) => bar,
            None => {
                let new_bar = Bar::clone(&self.0);
                self.0 = Arc::new(new_bar);
                Arc::get_mut(&mut self.0).unwrap()
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    Foo(Arc::new(Bar)).bar_mut();
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
 *  Executing task: cargo check 

    Checking testproj v0.1.0 (/home/dspyz/testproj)
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `self.0` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:13:42
   |
9  |       fn bar_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Bar {
   |                  - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
10 |           match Arc::get_mut(&mut self.0) {
   |           -                  ----------- mutable borrow occurs here
   |  _________|
   | |
11 | |             Some(bar) => bar,
12 | |             None => {
13 | |                 let new_bar = Bar::clone(&self.0);
   | |                                          ^^^^^^^ immutable borrow occurs here
...  |
16 | |             }
17 | |         }
   | |_________- returning this value requires that `self.0` is borrowed for `'1`

error[E0506]: cannot assign to `self.0` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:14:17
   |
9  |       fn bar_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Bar {
   |                  - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
10 |           match Arc::get_mut(&mut self.0) {
   |           -                  ----------- borrow of `self.0` occurs here
   |  _________|
   | |
11 | |             Some(bar) => bar,
12 | |             None => {
13 | |                 let new_bar = Bar::clone(&self.0);
14 | |                 self.0 = Arc::new(new_bar);
   | |                 ^^^^^^ assignment to borrowed `self.0` occurs here
15 | |                 Arc::get_mut(&mut self.0).unwrap()
16 | |             }
17 | |         }
   | |_________- returning this value requires that `self.0` is borrowed for `'1`

error[E0499]: cannot borrow `self.0` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:15:30
   |
9  |       fn bar_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Bar {
   |                  - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
10 |           match Arc::get_mut(&mut self.0) {
   |           -                  ----------- first mutable borrow occurs here
   |  _________|
   | |
11 | |             Some(bar) => bar,
12 | |             None => {
13 | |                 let new_bar = Bar::clone(&self.0);
14 | |                 self.0 = Arc::new(new_bar);
15 | |                 Arc::get_mut(&mut self.0).unwrap()
   | |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
16 | |             }
17 | |         }
   | |_________- returning this value requires that `self.0` is borrowed for `'1`

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0499, E0502, E0506.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0499`.
error: could not compile `testproj` due to 3 previous errors
```

- The terminal process "cargo 'check'" failed to launch (exit code: 101).
- Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The borrow checker is not perfect and there are still cases where it has a hard time determining the lifetimes involved. There are improvements with each release, but at the moment it is having a hard time figuring out how to assign the lifetimes in your code.

What happens is it sees that the function should return a value `&'0 mut Bar` and assigns that lifetime `'0` to the output of `Arc::get_mut`. However, this would mean that the mutable borrow used would also need to live for the duration of the function causing the error when you then attempt to re-use those values later in the function. Hopefully this will be fixed in later releases of the Rust compiler.

It is annoying, but we can avoid the issue by checking the `None` case first. With a bit of luck the compiler should be able to optimize it to the same output.

```rust
fn bar_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Bar {
    if Arc::get_mut(&mut self.0).is_none() {
        self.0 = Arc::new(Bar::clone(&*self.0));
    }
    
    Arc::get_mut(&mut self.0).unwrap()
}
```

Comment: Initially I thought there was a synchronization problem here because what if someone else clones the arc in between the two get_mut calls, but if you're the only owner then I suppose there's no one else who _can_ clone the arc so actually it's fine

Comment: No wait, there could be weak references. Someone could upgrade a weak reference in between the two get_mut calls causing the unwrap to fail

Comment: @DavidSpies, `Arc::get_mut` can only succeed if we hold the only reference (`Arc::strong_count(&x) + Arc::weak_count(&x) == 1`), so that should not be an issue. If that was possible, then it would break Rust's thread safety promise since it would allow someone to gain both a mutable and immutable reference to the same location in memory in safe Rust.

Comment: It depends how `get_mut` is implemented. If it invalidates the weak pointers before returning a mutable reference that's still safe...
Except then I guess the weak pointers wouldn't be _able_ to upgrade after the first call because they've been invalidated... So this works for either possible semantics of `get_mut`